# В какую сторону двигаться? Cookie (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, cookie

Уважаемые доны. Прошу направить меня в нужную степь и по возможности подсказать как действовать.

Идея такова: имеется шапка с двумя блоками (серый и синий). Когда пользователь заходит на сайт вкладка "Частным лицам" по умолчанию активна (на картинке_1 это видно) и пользователь может переходить по ссылкам  в синей части, таким как: "Каталог", "Услуг и цены", "Межгород" и тд. При этом вкладка "Частным лицам" остается активной. А когда Пользователь нажимает на ссылку "Юридическим лицам", то вкладка "Юридическим лицам" должна становится активной и пользователь может переходить по другим ссылкам меню в синей части (картинка_2), а вкладка "Юридическим лицам" должна оставаться активной. Собственно как должны меняться ссылки в синей части меню это соображу. А вот в остальном задачу не соображу как реализовать. [image: картинка_1][image: картинка_2]

Comment: То есть, пункты меню разные для Частным и Юрид?

Comment: Да. У частным лицам href=/, а у юр лицам href = /yurlic/

Comment: Вы хотите сделать отдельную ссылку для юр.лиц или просто функционал переключения этих вкладок на javascript'е ?

Comment: Дело в том что во вкладке юр.лицам и так находится отдельная ссылка. скорее всего, необходим, функционал переключения этих вкладок. Я предполагаю, что это можно реализовать через cookie.

Comment: Но только как именно это сделать, пока не знаю. Прошу помощи

Comment: для одних страниц хедер с "ЧЛ", для других пунктов, которые относятся к "ЮР" - другой хедер, никаких куков не нужно, всё, что нужно заменить в хедере - класс, который отвечает за подсветку активной вкладки, и поменять ссылки на стр. и их название